# How to join points using lines and spacing text ticks in the x axis in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data on jeans and I want it to plot it in the most understandable way focusing on the sizes available.

```
jeans <-  tribble(~ category, ~ brand, ~size_value,
"Jeans","BE GANESHA","38",
"Jeans","BE GANESHA","40",
"Jeans","BE GANESHA","42",
"Jeans","BE GANESHA","44",
"Jeans","BE GANESHA","34",
"Jeans","BE GANESHA","36",
"Jeans","Bendita Be","M",
"Jeans","Bendita Be","XL",
"Jeans","By Florencia","0",
"Jeans","By Florencia","1",
"Jeans","By Florencia","2",
"Jeans","By Florencia","3",
"Jeans","CLARA AGUAYO","U",
"Jeans","Caro Criado","L",
"Jeans","Caro Criado","M",
"Jeans","Caro Criado","XS",
"Jeans","Caro Criado","S",
"Jeans","Caro Criado","XL",
"Jeans","Joséphine","32",
"Jeans","Joséphine","34",
"Jeans","Joséphine","36",
"Jeans","Joséphine","38",
"Jeans","Joséphine","40",
"Jeans","LAS MARCAS","L",
"Jeans","LAS MARCAS","M",
"Jeans","LAS MARCAS","S",
"Jeans","LAS MARCAS","XL",
"Jeans","LAS MARCAS","XS",
"Jeans","LAS MARCAS","XXL",
"Jeans","LIMITE","1",
"Jeans","LIMITE","2",
"Jeans","LIMITE","3",
"Jeans","LIMITE","4",
"Jeans","LIMITE","5",
"Jeans","LIMITE","6",
"Jeans","LIMITE","0",
"Jeans","MARIMBA MULTIMARCAS","31",
"Jeans","MUTMA","26",
"Jeans","MUTMA","27",
"Jeans","MUTMA","28",
"Jeans","MUTMA","29",
"Jeans","MUTMA","30",
"Jeans","MUTMA","31",
"Jeans","Margara Shaw","L",
"Jeans","Margara Shaw","M",
"Jeans","Margara Shaw","S",
"Jeans","Margara Shaw","XL",
"Jeans","Margara Shaw","XS",
"Jeans","Margara Shaw","XXL",
"Jeans","Margara Shaw","4XL")

jeans_pants %>% 
    mutate(size_value = case_when(
              size_value == "S/M" ~ "S/M ", 
              size_value == "M/L" ~ "M/L ", 
              size_value == "L/XL" ~ "L/XL ",
              size_value == "S/M" ~ "S/M ", 
              size_value == "M/L" ~ "M/L ", 
              size_value == "L/XL" ~ "L/XL ",
              size_value == "XL" ~ "XL    ",
              size_value == "XXL" ~ "XXL    ",
              size_value == "XXXL" ~ "XXXL    ",
              .default = as.character(size_value)),
           size_value = factor(size_value, levels = c("U", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
                                                      "6",
                                                      "S/M ", "M/L ", "L/XL ",
                                                      "XXS", "XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL   ", 
                                                      "XXL    ", "XXXL    ", "4XL",
                                                      "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
                                                      "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", 
                                                      "34", "36", "38", "40", "42", 
                                                      "44"))) %>% 
    arrange(brand, desc(size_value)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(size_value, brand)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = size_value), alpha = .6, size = 3) +
    scale_color_manual(values = rep(c("#8E6151", "#988880"), 38)) + 
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(r = 22))))
```

In the first place, I want to draw a line between the points of the same scale (I'm going to show a picture above of the desired outfit). And then, I tried manually to space in the axis XL, XXL, and XXXL but I can't.

[image]

I would really appreciate the help and any further suggestions on visualisation.

Here I left an example of a brand with multiple sizes' scales:

```
data <- tribble(~brand,~size_value,
"BE GANESHA","38",
"BE GANESHA","40",
"BE GANESHA","42",
"BE GANESHA","44",
"BE GANESHA","34",
"BE GANESHA","36",
"Margo Baridon","24",
"Margo Baridon","26",
"Margo Baridon","28",
"Margo Baridon","30",
"Margo Baridon","32",
"Margo Baridon","34",
"BE GANESHA","M",
"BE GANESHA","L",
"BE GANESHA","S",
"BE GANESHA","XL",
"BE GANESHA","XS",
"BE GANESHA","XXL",
"Margo Baridon","L",
"Margo Baridon","M",
"Margo Baridon","S",
"Margo Baridon","XS",
"Margo Baridon","24",
"Margo Baridon","26",
"Margo Baridon","28",
"Margo Baridon","30",
"Margo Baridon","32",
"Margo Baridon","34",
"Margo Baridon","XL")
```

Comment: FYI, your `factor` level for `"XL"` only has 3 spaces though you rewrote it with four trailing spaces, so all of your `XL` data is getting `NA`. Easily fixed.

Comment: I think what you're attempting to do by padding with spaces is to force specific spacing for a discrete axis. I don't think this is possible. I suggest the path forward might be to plot on a continuous x-axis, control axis ticks and labels with `scale_x_continuous(values=, labels=)`, and not worry about hard-coding the spaces themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that `ggplot2` does not support arbitrary spacing on a discrete axis (I'm curious to find solutions that do!). In the interim, let's shift to a continuous x-axis, predefining the corresponding x locations based on the desired widths. (This precludes the need to add spaces.)

```r
sizes <- tibble(size_value = c("U", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
                               "S/M", "M/L", "L/XL",
                               "XXS", "XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", 
                               "XXL", "XXXL", "4XL",
                               "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
                               "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", 
                               "34", "36", "38", "40", "42", "44"),
                x = lag(cumsum(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                             1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), default=0)
)
```

(The order and widths were inferred from your previous code.)

We'll `left_join` this onto your `jeans`. Note that I am not guarding against any `jeans$size_value` not found in `sizes$size_value`; if that occurs, `x=` will be assigned `NA` and likely not plotted.

Since you wanted lines among points grouped by `brand`, I'll add that too (under the dots), though that's "just because". I also added `theme_bw()` to simplify the theme, more akin to what you had as a demo in the question.

```r
jeans %>%
  left_join(sizes, by = "size_value") %>%
  mutate(size_value = factor(size_value, levels = sizes$size_value)) %>%
  arrange(brand, desc(size_value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, brand)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = brand)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = size_value), alpha = .6, size = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(values = rep(c("#8E6151", "#988880"), nrow(sizes))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = sizes$x, labels = sizes$size_value) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(r = 22)))
```

[image]

Comment: This works (even though I don't fully enjoy visually the spaces on the x axis). I have cases where brands produce on different clothing scales and the geom_line does not work. I added an example on the original question.

Comment: I can only _infer_ what grouping should be done, there's nothing defined. I'll take a guess ...

Comment: mutate(scale_talle = case_when(
               size_value == "U" ~ "Talle Único",              size_value %in% c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6") ~ "Talles 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 & 6",
#              size_value %in% c("S/M", "M/L", "L/XL") ~ "Talles S/M, M/L & L/XL",
#              size_value %in% c("XXS", "XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL", "4XL") ~ "Talles XXS, XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL, XXXL & 4XL", 
#              size_value %in% c("22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "36", "38", "40", "42", "44") ~ "Talles 22 al 44"))

Comment: if you already know what the groups should be, just use `scale_talle` as your group variable, does that work for you?

Comment: Because it tries to unify them as a connected scatterplot.

Comment: try `geom_line(aes(group=interaction(scale_talle, brand)))` or similar